# "Could we move the meeting to 3pm?"

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

> "Could we move the meeting to 3pm?"

Is it a correct way to ask somebody to postpone a meeting? If so, does it sound natural? If not, what could be used instead? 
Can one use "shift" instead of "move" in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common business jargon to say "move" for "reschedule".

"Shift" is also used, but in American English it suggests a systematic change ("All the meetings are shifted back an hour"); in British English it suggests a move is difficult.

Comment: I don't think the American/British difference is so clear cut.  As a BE speaker, "All the meetings are shifted back an hour" seems normal.

Comment: Perhaps it's just an _additional_ meaning.  When I hear an BrEn speaker say he had to "shift" something, he always seem to imply it's something heavy.